# What does the irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

So here'as the problem

> Find the monic irreducible polynomial  $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ for $i+ \sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Erm...huh? Okay, so a minimal polynomial $m$ is what I need, and since $g(x)=m \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$, this is a polynomial over the rationals. i.e. its coefficients must be rational.

Immediately before this question, I solved

> Find the monic irreducible polynomial  $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ for $i+ \sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

The last "over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$" doesn't make sense to me, $m=g(x)$ is sorted for the polynomial, and I know $i+\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{C}$. I don't know where this "over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$" applies to. What's it talking about?

Comment: I believe the problem should say $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}(i)(x)$.

Comment: So you reckon it's a typo on the problem? It does make sense that way. Though, repeating it at the end "over *whatever field*" seems redundant...

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is a field. You are asked to find a polynomial $P(X)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that $P(i+\sqrt{3})=0$ and $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. I think in the question it should be written : $g(X)\in\mathbb{Q}(i)[X]$.

Comment: That confirms that the question had a typo then, thank you two, glad I got that cleared.